# Assign Id based on class

Tags: jquery

I have Html with class name Style1, Style2 style.... and I want to assign id based on my assigned class define in static HTML. I want to assign Id in dynamic section. I don't have any access of Dyanmic HTML I want assign through jQuery.

Static Class name section.

```
<div id="mediafarmplugin">
  <div class="style1">Get External Content</div>
  <div class="style2">Get External Content</div>
  <div class="style3">Get External Content</div>
  <div class="style4">Get External Content</div>
  <div class="style...">......</div>
</div>
```

Dynamic Assign Id based on class name style

```
<div id="table">
  <div id="style1">Style1 appear</div>
  <div id="style2">Style2 appear</div>
  <div id="style3">Style3 appear</div>
  <div id="style...infinte number">Style... Infinate number appear</div>
</div>
```

Please help me

Comment: Please rephrase your question, currently it doesnt make much sense. You mention "child infinite counter", what is that? You also mention "Assign Id based on class name style" but we have no idea what that means and your html uses no classes at all....

Comment: I have update question I hope it will clear you. If you have any idea about that help me.

Comment: Please add js fiddle.

Comment: Not realy clearer. You keep saying `class` but you have no classes in your html, only ids. `<input type="text" class="some-class some-other-class" id="some-id">` ... see the difference?

Comment: Can you post an example of what the html should look like after the changes?

Comment: Additionally **why do you want to do this, what does it accomplish?** I ask because there is often a much simpler and more appropriate way to achieve the end result with questions like this (no offense intended)

Comment: See I have changed id into class

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("div").each(function(){
           if((this).attr('class') != undefined)
               $(this).attr("id",$(this).attr("class"));
      });

  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the JavaScript, I'm not that good at jQuery. Details are annotated in the code.

**Note:** I mentioned that the containers are the same width as the content, sorry about that. I had confused you question with another question, but fortunately the rest of the answer still applies to your question.

```js
$(function() {
  var divs = document.querySelectorAll('#static div');
  var divArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(divs);
  var dyn = document.getElementById('dynamic');
  for (var i = 0; i < divArray.length; i++) {
    var klass = divArray[i].getAttribute('class');
    var klone = divArray[i].cloneNode(true);
    klone.setAttribute('id', klass);
    dyn.appendChild(klone);
  }
});

/* JavaScript Breakdown */
// 1. jQuery ready wrapper
// 2. Make a NodeList of all divs inside of section#static
// 3. Convert NodeList into an array
// 4. Reference section#dynamic
// 5. Iterate through divArray
// 6. Retrieve each of the divs' class
// 7. Clone each div
// 8. Each clone get's an id based on the class of the original element
// 9. Clone is appended to section#dynamic
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
section {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  outline: 3px dashed blue;
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: -webkit-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  margin: 20px;
}
div {
  outline: 2px solid red;
  width: 100px;
}
p {
  margin: 10px;
}
[id^="style"]:after {
  content: ' ★';
  font-size: 20px;
  color: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="static">
  <div class="style1">Get External Content</div>
  <div class="style2">Get External Content</div>
  <div class="style3">Get External Content</div>
  <div class="style4">Get External Content</div>
</section>

<p>The sections have the width of their contents.<sup>CSS 8,9,10</sup></p>
<p>The cloned divs below each has a gold star. This is proof that each clone has an id that starts with "style".<sup>CSS 17</sup> You can use the dev tools to view the clones' ids</p>
<p>
  <section id="dynamic"></section>
```